# Add Controls to UIPageViewController

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, controls, uipageviewcontroller

I need to add some buttons to my UIPageViewController. I followed this tutorial and you will notice that at the bottom there is a button below the dots. How do I accomplish a similar thing? I need to add 3 buttons to the view.

Tutorial: http://www.appcoda.com/uipageviewcontroller-storyboard-tutorial/

Thanks in advance, and sorry if I have missed something obvious. I have searched quite a bit.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
     [super viewDidLoad];

    _pageImages = @[@"Step1.png", @"Step2.png", @"Step3.png"];

    self.mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard_iPhone" bundle:nil];

    self.pageViewController = [self.mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"PageViewController"];

    self.pageViewController.dataSource = self;

    RTMPageContentViewController *startingViewController = [self viewControllerAtIndex:0];
    NSArray *viewControllers = @[startingViewController];
    [self.pageViewController setViewControllers:viewControllers direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward animated:YES completion:nil];

    self.pageViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);

    [self addChildViewController:_pageViewController];
    [self.view addSubview:_pageViewController.view];
    [self.pageViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just realized what the answer is:

If I change the frame height of the `UIPageViewController`, it gives me space below.

Answer (score 0):

Its quite simple, follow the steps..

**`Step 1.`**

Setup your UIPageViewController in Storyboard.

**`Step 2`**

Add Buttons on your ViewController not PageViewController.

**`Step 3`**

**Instantiate** UIPageViewController using code below

```
_pageViewController=[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"PageViewController"];
```

**`Step 4`**

You can chose your ViewController to setup all the **datasources** and **delegates** for UIPageViewController, and then finally add the UIPageViewController's view as subview on ViewController, like

```
_pageViewController.dataSource = self;
[self addChildViewController:_pageViewController];
[self.view addSubview:_pageViewController.view];
[self.pageViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
```

Cheers.

Comment: I have already done all of this, but my buttons do not appear. I will add some code to maybe help.

Comment: Do I need to be using autolayout or anything like that for it to work?